# Any algorithm that mangles/hashes a string but can be matched against?

Tags: string, algorithm, hash

Usage case: client needs to send a huge string over HTTP. The server replies whether the string contains some substring. However, huge string is huge. This system is as a result really inefficient. Moreover, huge string contains some sensitive info, so this is really insecure.

Is there some pseudo-hashing mechanism that somehow summarizes a big string into some number, which all substrings of this big string would hash to the same number, but non-substrings will with high probability not hash to this big string?

Comment: I don't know how to prove it, but I find it exceedingly improbable that such a thing would be possible.  For a start, consider that "all substrings of a huge string" is likely to contain "a", "b", "c", etc.

Comment: Why is client sending the huge string anyway? Can't the client itself search for the substring?

Comment: Hmm. Disproof of myself: Assume such a function exists. Then this can be reworded as all strings hash to the same number as any *superstring* of the string. Assume "" hashes to `0`. By this argument all strings hash to `0`, which is a contradiction that this can be used as a determiner of substrings.

Comment: BTW: for every string of lenght N, there are N(N-1) possible substrings.

Comment: @wildplasser: That's not correct. A substring can be thought of as a placement of two markers in the string, one designating the beginning and the other designating the end. There are `n + 1` possible positions for the markers from which we must select two. However, this neglects to count the empty string. Therefore, there are `1 + (n + 1 choose 2) = 1 + n(n + 1) / 2` possible substrings. However, this reasoning assumes a repeated substring is counted multiple times, once for each occurrence.

Comment: Ok, I missed the /2. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there some pseudo-hashing mechanism that somehow summarizes a big string into some number, which all substrings of this big string would hash to the same number, but non-substrings will with high probability not hash to this big string?

No.

Let `f` be such a hash. Consider a string `s` and non-substring `t`. Note that `s` and `t` are substrings of `s + t`. Therefore, `s` and `t` have the same hash (i.e., `f(s) = f(t) = f(s + t)`). This is contrary to the requirement that `f(s) != f(t)` with high probability.

In particular, with `s = ""`, we see that all strings `t` have `f(s) = f(t)`, so that `f` is constant and equal to `f("")`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some pseudo-hashing mechanism that somehow summarizes a big string into some number, which all substrings of this big string would hash to the same number, but non-substrings will with high probability not hash to this big string?

I guess I'll have to explain why this won't happen:

```
String string = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
```

That means, according to your request, that every single letter in this will hash to the same value. Hashing algorithms are deterministic. In this example, `t -> 5`, `h -> 5`, `e -> 5`... And so on, but if you have some string:

```
String string2 = "hello there";
```

Then now, you want `h` to hash to something different, and you want `e` to hash to something different, so given the exact same input, you want a different value. This defeats the definition of a mathematical function.

*What does this mean?*

Well, without any aspect of determinism in your function, your data has no repeatable mapping between a value and the letter that is being hashed, meaning your data is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a constant length for the substrings you could do what many file-sharing programs do and use a list of hashes or something like the tiger-tree hash.

List of hashes: Make a hash for every chunk of the file of some pre-set length (say 64kB), then transmit a list of these hashes so these chunks can be verified.

Tiger-Tree hash: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree#Tiger_tree_hash
Basically build a binary tree of hashes with the leaves being hashes of chunks like in a list of hashes.

If you need to match to every possible substring instead of just pre-defined chunks this isn't going to work though.

Answer (score 0):

All substrings doesn't sound viable, but I imagine you may have some constraints on your substrings you haven't yet told us about.

If you do your substrings block-aligned or whitespace-aligned or something, you might look into using a bloom filter, EG: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/drs-bloom-filter/1.01 .  Bloom Filters can store members of a set and be used for testing set membership, at times with as little as one bit per element.  They do sometimes give false positives, but with a user-adjustable probability of a false positive.